# AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation is not showing up with a Route Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I am trying to create a custom template in the CloudFormation designer on AWS. However, AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation is not showing up. I am following a tutorial and the tutorial it shows up as purple dot in the Route Table. On my end when trying to replicate his steps my route table has no purple dot thus has no AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation. Im confused. How can I fix this?

**The tutorials view:**
[image]

**My current design space view:**
[image]

The one things I notice is im missing these colored dots the tutorial view has, but the question is why?
[image]

I followed the tutorial and created a VPC, created a Subnet, created an Internet Gateway, and added a Route Table. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ETlJh9ZKUU&t=127s) is the tutorial I am following

Answer (score 1):

you can manually add it on the template.

some of the item like VPCGatewayAttachment, SubnetRouteTableAssociation, SecurityGroupIngress is not showing up in designer.